# Change the font colour of combo box in delphi firemonkey mobile

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I have created application using Delphi XE7 firemonkey for Android mobile. In that i'm using Combobox. How can I change the font colour of the combo box?

Comment: It's not possible to change the font or color by editing the properties of the combobox. In Android it all changes back to default but you can use the following link to change the font, but it will change all of them! http://firemonkeyblog.blogspot.nl/2014/12/using-custom-fonts-in-android-delphi.html

Comment: I have seen this link and I'm not able to understand.Is there any sample code.? And in this link, changing the font colour  is not explained

Comment: Changing the color of the font isn't possible as far as I know. And don't know if there is any sample code for changing the font. Just follow the steps from the link

Comment: ok. If we need then we need to create new component only and no other  options right.?

Comment: Yes it changes all the fonts automaticly I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ComboBox1.ListBox.ListItems[0].TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.White;
  ComboBox1.ListBox.ListItems[0].StyledSettings := ComboBox1.ListBox.ListItems[0].StyledSettings
- [TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
```

The above code is working fine for changing the font color of the first item in the combo box "ComboBox1" in a firemonkey application.

Comment: wouldn't that change only the first item in the combo box?

Comment: Yeah. Only for the particular index, the font color will change.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code:

```
  for i := 0 to Combobox1.Count -1 do
  begin
    ComboBox1.ListItems[i].Text := ' Hello';
    ComboBox1.ListItems[i].Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
    ComboBox1.ListItems[i].Font.Size := 26;
    ComboBox1.ListItems[i].StyledSettings := [];
    ComboBox1.ListItems[i].Height := 30;
  end;
```

But it really works after I changed the property from ComboBox:
DropDownKind = Native to Custom